# How can I get 16 bit global elevation maps?

Tags: qgis, raster, elevation, rasterization, 3d-model

I'm a 3D artist working on a procedural planet generator, based on colour and height textures from real-life areas. I've been using the GeoTIFF files from NASA Visible Earth, but they all seem to be in 8 bit format which causes bad stepping artifacts when they're used as height maps.

Is there anywhere I can find global 16 bit height rasters, or is it possible for me to increase the bit depth of the ones from NASA Visible Earth?

Or are there any non-raster elevation datasets that I can convert into 16 bit rasters with QGIS? I suspect this would be the best method, but I don't know QGIS very well, so I have no idea how.

[image: screenshot from Substance Designer showing stepping artifacts on desert terrain]

Comment: https://gisgeography.com/free-global-dem-data-sources/ https://cgiarcsi.community/data/srtm-90m-digital-elevation-database-v4-1/ (lower resolution 90m)

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking for the **Translate** tool in QGIS. There, select UInt16 as the output format and you should be fine.

However, in order to avoid the *terracing* you shared on your OP, you need to **Rescale** your GeoTIFF first: in order to do so, you have to stretch your elevation between 0 and 65,535, as that's the pixel range 16-bit TIFFs can hold.

In this case, let's imagine your elevation goes from 100 to 378 m. Using the **Calculator** in QGIS, what we are going to do is to make 100 become 0 and 378 become 65,535.

Thus, the formula you need is the following one:

*(File Name – Lowest Value) ÷ (Highest Value – Lowest Value) * 65,535*

Comment: This doesn't eliminate difference between 2 distinct value on neighboring terraces.

Comment: True. For that, what I do is combine different smoothed/blurred versions  of the resulting tiff in Photoshop/Gimp. See the following tutorial for instance https://somethingaboutmaps.wordpress.com/2022/01/13/towards-less-blender-y-relief/

Answer (score 1):

For further information on this issue, you can always read this famous article by Daniel Huffman. More specifically, regarding your issue, you can check steps from 6 to 8:

[Daniel Huffman´s tutorial](https://somethingaboutmaps.wordpress.com/blender-relief-tutorial-getting-set-up/)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).